# Need to close a while loop with a user input

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to make a small game that asks trivia questions. I have it almost ready but I can't figure out how to close the while loop I have.

```
while True:
        Choose = input("What topic would you like?")
        if Choose == "History" or Choose == "history":
            import History
            break
        elif Choose == "Geo" or Choose == "geo" or Choose == "geography" or Choose == "Geography":
            import Geo
            break
        elif Choose == "I'm done!":
            print("Thanks for playing!")
            break
        else: 
            print("Sorry, please enter a valid topic")
            continue
```

Comment: `break` ends the loop. You should do that when they enter a valid input, not an invalid input.

Comment: What do you mean by "closing" the loop ? In Python you don't have to declare that you close a block, it is all specified by the indent.

Comment: There's no need for the `try/except`. You're not doing any type conversion that might raise an exception.

Comment: What do you mean by close? You have a `break` in the `else` statement that when someone enters an invalid topic it exits the while loop.

Comment: @Barmar That helped so much! Thanks!

Comment: @MateoVial I want the user to be able to pick either History or Geo or to just end the program.

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide Yeah I fixed that! Works much better now!

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    Choose = input("What topic would you like?")
    if Choose == "History" or Choose == "history":
        import History
    elif Choose == "Geo" or Choose == "geo" or Choose == "geography" or Choose == "Geography":
        import Geo
    elif Choose == 'quit':
        print("Ok, bye bye!")
        break
    else: 
        print("Sorry, please enter a valid topic")
```

Some details that you might find interesting:

```
Choose.lower() == "history"
```

can be used instead of doing if X or x. This also applies to Geo/geo, etc.

Naming variables with lower cases is generally the standard. `choose`

Comment: Thanks you so much! That will be really helpfull!